# Connecting varying tilemap layouts at possible connection points?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, tilemap

I'm building an isometric 3D ARPG in **Unity3D**, and

- I have a **tilemap**, for example a **dungeon**.
- I have **tiles marked** where a **door could be placed**.
- I select a **random "could-be-a-door" tile** from the tilemap.
- I "receive" an **any shaped room**, which could be a **prefab**, or a **generated one** as well. This room got **tiles marked** for **door placement** as well.

**Without editing anything:**

- how could I easily determine whether **this room** could be **connected** to the **existing dungeon** via the **selected connection point**? (and of course find the solution if it could be)

  - by (valid) connecting I mean: only their doors and walls can overlap, but nothing else. (and removing the duplicates, creating the door itself, etc)

(Of course rooms can differ from rectangles)

[image]

Comment: You show in your example a rotation of the tilemap. Is that intended in your implementation, or will you maintain a standard orientation? I ask because TileMap and Grid coordinate systems are on the local space, so if you rotate the room youll have to do extra logic to find the correct coordinate (moving up in world space may mean moving left in local space, etc). Maintaining a standard orientation will make your Procedural a lot easier as well, as you can check bottom walls to top walls only, left to right, and so on. Rather than having to check  after rotation several times.

Comment: By this definition, all rooms can connect with dungeons, when you say only doors and walls can overlap, are you claiming that you want to make sure that if multiple doors exist on either the room and/or dungeon that they only overlap with doors coming from the other piece?

Comment: also what about door to empty space? That is not covered by your definition of valid.